# Asterisk/FreePBX queues no longer working

Tags: asterisk, queue, freepbx

Incoming calls go straight through to failover regardless what other settings are. I have deleted the queue and rebuilt it, nothing seams to fix it...

Asterisk 16

Freepbx 15

Debian 10

There is a warning message "Unable to join queue" even though it seams there is no reason, a caller cant join the queue and have noticed that the queue doesnt seam to apprear in the asterisk cli

```
localhost*CLI> queue show 200
No such queue: 200.
```

**LOGS:**

```
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:39] QueueLog("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "200,1619828810.454,NONE,DID,10017238") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:40] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "QAANNOUNCE=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:41] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "VQ_AANNOUNCE=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:42] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "QMOH=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:43] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "VQ_MOH=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:44] ExecIf("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "0?Set(__MOHCLASS=)") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:45] ExecIf("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "0?Set(CHANNEL(musicclass)=)") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:46] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "QMAXWAIT=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:47] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "VQ_MAXWAIT=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:48] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "QUEUENUM=200") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:49] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "QUEUEJOINTIME=1619828822") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:50] Queue("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "200,t,,,,,,,,") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] WARNING[18933][C-0000000f] app_queue.c: Unable to join queue '200'
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:51] Macro("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "blkvm-clr,") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-blkvm-clr:1] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "SHARED(BLKVM,SIP/CrazyTel-00000019)=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-blkvm-clr:2] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "GOSUB_RETVAL=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-blkvm-clr:3] MacroExit("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:52] Gosub("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "sub-record-cancel,s,1()") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@sub-record-cancel:1] Return("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:53] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "__NODEST=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:54] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "_QUEUE_PRIO=0") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:55] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "QDEST=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:56] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "VQ_DEST=") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:57] GotoIf("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "1?ext-queues,200,1:,,") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx_builtins.c: Goto (ext-queues,200,1)
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [200@ext-queues:1] Macro("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "user-callerid,") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:1] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "TOUCH_MONITOR=1619828810.454") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:2] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "AMPUSER=0405652555") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:3] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "HOTDESCKCHAN=CrazyTel-00000019") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:4] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "HOTDESKEXTEN=CrazyTel") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:5] Set("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "HOTDESKCALL=0") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:6] ExecIf("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "0?Set(HOTDESKCALL=1)") in new stack
[2021-05-01 08:27:02] VERBOSE[18933][C-0000000f] pbx.c: Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:7] ExecIf("SIP/CrazyTel-00000019", "0?Set(CALLERID(name)=)") in new
```

**queues_additional.conf**

```
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
;          Do NOT edit this file as it is auto-generated by FreePBX.             ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
; For information on adding additional paramaters to this file, please visit the ;
; FreePBX.org wiki page, or ask on IRC. This file was created by the new FreePBX ;
; BMO - Big Module Object. Any similarity in naming with BMO from Adventure Time ;
; is totally deliberate.                                                         ;
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
[200]
announce-frequency=30
announce-holdtime=yes
announce-position=yes
autofill=no
autopause=no
autopausebusy=no
autopausedelay=0
autopauseunavail=no
joinempty=yes
leavewhenempty=no
maxlen=100
memberdelay=0
min-announce-frequency=15
musicclass=default
penaltymemberslimit=1
periodic-announce-frequency=30
queue-callswaiting=queue-callswaiting
queue-thankyou=queue-thankyou
queue-thereare=queue-thereare
queue-youarenext=queue-youarenext
reportholdtime=no
retry=5
ringinuse=yes
servicelevel=60
setinterfacevar=yes
strategy=ringall
timeout=15
timeoutpriority=app
timeoutrestart=no
weight=0
wrapuptime=0
context=ivr-1
member=Local/614########@from-queue/n,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...
queues.conf had reset and was missing `#include queues_additional.conf` where freepbx was writing to